# module `Qt.labs.qmlmodels` is not installed

Tags: python, qt, qml, qtquick2, archlinux

I'm trying to run the [example of item selection for a `TableView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-tableview.html#selecting-items), but it needs `Qt.labs.qmlmodels`. The problem is, that doesn't appear to be installed, and I can't find the correct package.

`main.qml`:

```
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 700
    title: "Test"

    TableView {
        id: tableView

        anchors.fill: parent
        clip: true

        model: TableModel {
            rows: [{
                "name": "Harry"
            }, {
                "name": "Hedwig"
            }]

            TableModelColumn {
                display: "name"
            }

        }

        selectionModel: ItemSelectionModel {
            model: tableView.model
        }

        delegate: Rectangle {
            required property bool selected

            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 30
            color: selected ? "blue" : "lightgray"

            Text {
                text: display
            }

        }

    }

}
```

`main.py`:

```py
import sys
import signal

from PyQt6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

# Make app respond to Ctrl-C
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)  # type: ignore

engine.load("main.qml")

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Running `main.py` gives me this error:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///home/user/test2/main.qml:1:1: module "Qt.labs.qmlmodels" is not installed
```

- OS: Arch Linux
- Qt version: 6.3.1-1

Answer (score 0):

Please read this:

[qt-6.4-qml-python-missing-liberary-module-qt5compat-graphical-effects-is-not-installed](https://www.it-hinca.de/de/blog/blog-news/qt-6-4-qml-python-missing-liberary-module-qt5compat-graphical-effects-is-not-installed.html)

Just now, I try to change matplotlib-backends' version. I find that the pyqt6 folder doesn't have the Qt folder.

So I copy that in pyside6 lib to pyqt lib.

For me is:from `D:\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PySide6\qml\Qt` to `D:\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyQt6\Qt6\qml`.

Please try this, hope it work.